# cruce de 2 tablas y obtener el ultimo registro por fecha en sql

Tags: sql

Consulta: Tengo 2 tablas `A` y `B`.

En la tabla `A` requiero traer el campo `FECHA_RESPUESTA` de la tabla `B`, la condición sea por la última fecha de respuesta de la tabla `B`.

```
Tabla A 

ID  -   FECHA_INGRESO   -   PRODUCTO

3349793 -   2018-01-07 18:08    -   A
3356512 -   2018-01-11 10:18    -   B
3343136 -   2018-01-03 15:12    -   C
3343207 -   2018-01-03 15:41    -   D
3343708 -   2018-01-03 21:33    -   E

TABLA B

ID  -   FECHA_RESPUESTA -   PRODUCTO

3349793 -   2018-01-08 17:34    -   A
3349793 -   2018-01-08 17:37    -   A
3356512 -   2018-01-11 18:02    -   B
3356512 -   2018-01-12 09:09    -   B
3343136 -   2018-01-04 16:16    -   C
3343207 -   2018-01-04 16:32    -   D
3343708 -   2018-01-04 18:15    -   E
```

Comment: Tiene sentido que solo uses una tabla y "FECHA_INGRESO " y "FECHA_RESPUESTA" sean columnas de esa tabla?

Answer (score 1):

Si no entendí mal tu pregunta la respuesta pasa por un `LEFT` o eventualmente un `INNER JOIN` entre las dos tablas. En el primer caso traerías todos los registros de la tabla A más los registros de la tabla B que coincidan por el `ID`, en el caso de un `INNER` únicamente los registros cuyo `ID`se encuentren en ambas tablas.

Con respecto a la fecha, deberías usar la función de agregación `MAX` sobre `FECHA_RESPUESTA` y agrupamos el resto de las columnas

```
SELECT A.ID,
       A.FECHA_INGRESO,
       A.PRODUCTO,
       MAX(B.FECHA_RESPUESTA)
       FROM TablaA A
       LEFT JOIN TablaB B
           ON A.ID = B.ID
       GROUP BY A.ID,
                A.FECHA_INGRESO,
                A.PRODUCTO
```